# WPF TreeView structure lost after update through ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I am developing a WPF project which, for now, implements a `ComboBox`, `Button`, `ICommand` and `TreeView`. The `TreeView` is generated through the `ICommand` interface that binds to the `Button`. While running the app and after selecting the item from the `ComboBox` + clicking the `Button` my TreeView is displayed as expected. The xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <vm:RevitVM x:Key="viewmodel"/>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ParentNew}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ChildNew}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource viewmodel}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UniqueAreaTypes}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAreaType}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AreaType}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Search" 
            Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"
            Grid.Row="5"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="4"/>
        <TreeView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1">
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding FamilyList}" Header="Test"
                         IsExpanded="False"/>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
```

The problem arises when the TreeView is expanded followed by using the `Button` for the second time (regardless of the `ComboBox` selected item). My `TreeView` only displays the updated Parents and not the `Children`. It looks like the binding is somehow lost.

```
        public RevitVM()
        {
            SearchCommand = new SearchCommand(this);
            FamilyList = new ObservableCollection<ParentNew>();
        }



        public void SetTree()
        {
            FamilyList.Clear();
            foreach (var a in AreasToShow)
            {
                ParentNew parent = new ParentNew(); 
                parent.Name = a.Name;
                FamilyList.Add(parent); 
                ObservableCollection<ChildNew> children = new ObservableCollection<ChildNew>();
                foreach (var r in RoomsToShow)
                {
                    if (r.Position == a.Position) 
                    {
                        ChildNew child = new ChildNew();
                        child.Name = r.Name;
                        children.Add(child);
                    }
                }
                parent.Children = children;
            }
        }


        public void MakeQuery()
        {
            SetTree();
        }
```

Does this has to do with the fact that I am clearing and re-writing the property `ObservableCollection<ParentNew> FamilyList` through a `ICommand` interface?

```
public class SearchCommand : ICommand
{
    public RevitVM VM { get; set; }

    public SearchCommand(RevitVM revitVM)
    {
        VM = revitVM;
    }

    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
        VM.MakeQuery();
    }
```

The `ParentNew` class:

```
public class ParentNew
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ChildNew> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I was expecting the updated `FamilyList` property to be shown on the Window while maintaining its structure after expanding the tree and clicking the `Button`.

It is worth noting that if `TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` is set to `False`, **not** manually expanded and the `Button` clicked, then the `TreeView` maintain its structure with the updated `Children`.
When I set the `TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` to `True` in the xaml, the TreeView doesn't show the `Children` even if I am running the app for the first time. Is `TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` triggering something that I am not able to see?

At the moment I am not using any code behind and I don't intend to. I am also fairly new to the c# language and WPF so I tried to search for the answer by reading several StackOverflow posts on the subject but to no avail. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you assign Children collection (`parent.Children = children;`) but UI doesn't know about that.

To ensure that UI is updated, implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in ParentNew class and raise PropertyChanged event.

But there is also a simple fix - assign collection before adding parent object to FamilyList:

```
ObservableCollection<ChildNew> children = new ObservableCollection<ChildNew>();
parent.Children = children;
FamilyList.Add(parent); 

foreach (var r in RoomsToShow)
{
    if (r.Position == a.Position) 
    {
        ChildNew child = new ChildNew();
        child.Name = r.Name;
        children.Add(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Assigning the collection before adding parent object solves the issue.